# .Net Core - Using Authorization filter to check a variable from request and modify it

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization

In below code, I need to read value of variable from request and modify request object.

```
public class ApiAuthFilter : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // 1. read request object from context

        // 2. modify the value

        // 3. add the value and update request

    }
}
```

Comment: What value, can you give an example? Has it anything to do with authorization?

Comment: It's really not clear to me why you would want to do that at this point. Why not in an injected service or in the controller? Seems that it has nothing to do with authorization, you are not adding claims or so.

Comment: Could you share more details about your requirement?There are many variables in request,which one do you want to modify?

Comment: // .NET 2.1
// context.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
// .NET 3.1
// context.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify request object like below:

1.User:

```
public class User
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.ApiAuthFilter:

```
public class ApiAuthFilter : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //1.read request object from context
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        request.EnableRewind();
        request.Body.Position = 0;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            //2.modify the value
            var decriptedFromJavascript = "{ \"Id\":2,\"Name\":\"UR123456\"}"; 
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decriptedFromJavascript);
            //3. add the value and update request
            request.Body = new MemoryStream(bytes); 
        }
    }
}
```

3.Action:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
[ApiAuthFilter]
public User GetUser([FromBody]User user)
{
    return user;
}
```

4.Result:
[image]

Comment: In action, if i use - [ApiAuthFilter]  [Route("GetUser")] [HttpPost], not able to get values in user object

Comment: Did you use `[FromBody]`?Could you update your thread with your code?Then it would be better for us to resolve your issue.

Comment: The issue was with [IgnoreDataMember] attribute in request class.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        string authHeader = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = "value";
    }
```